# Run test multiple times in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

By default when you run a unit test from Visual Studio's Test Explorer, it only runs once. Is there a way to run it multiple times, like 100 times or something ? And then after running it multiple times, I get a report stating how many times the test passed/failed and what caused all the failures (if any) ?

Note: I looked at some other similar Stack Overflow threads but didn't see a solution that's applicable in my case.

Comment: That's not how Unit testing is supposed to work.  Why would a unit test have different results over multiple executions?  If you're introducing randomness, then it's not a unit test.

Comment: The test needs to execute some code which calls some other services which aren't mocked (reasons beyond the scope here) ... So we need to make sure the test is passing all the time and is not failing some weird reason due to calling the other services. I need to make sure the test is robust enough and will not have any false negatives because it will be used a lot in the future for downstream services to verify working state ..

Comment: This is why I want to run a test multiple times and see if it ever fails ..

Comment: If it helps, you can think of it as a functional test rather than a unit test .. Although the code is setup as a unit test ..

Comment: I think what you need is some kinda custom test suite that will sample multiple runs and come up with a fault tolerance. The test will be slow, and flaky. I am not aware Visual Studio provides this out of the box albeit there might be professional plugins available.

Comment: for new people, looks like there is a new option on right clicking a test, that lets you run a test until it fails.

Answer (score 7):

I think this is a perfectly legitimate question, because sometimes tests can be flaky due to use of AutoFixture or other intentionally random elements to populate test models. This randomness is valuable as it can discover unforeseen flaws in testing and bugs in production code.

I know of no professional plugin that gives Visual Studio this feature, but there is always the coding approach:

```c#
public class TestClass
{
    private Random _random;

    public TestClass()
    {
        _random = new Random();
    }

    [Fact]
    public void FlakyTest()
    {
        var number = _random.Next(10);
        Assert.True(number < 7);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void MyFlakyTestWorks100Times()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            var tests = new TestClass();
            tests.FlakyTest();
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Obviously you would want to seriously consider removing that looping test before you submit your work to your build pipeline!

Comment: Weirdly, this did not work for me using bunit. My single test failed more often, then the 1000 tests, which I had in the loop.

Answer (score 3):

In VS2022 there is a feature (since 17.4). In Test Explorer you can choose "Run Until Failure"

[image]

It will run 1000 times by default, it can be configured in VS Options under
Test / General > Group: Test Run

[image]